# SQL Email Verification Function using Regex

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a function in SQL Server 2005 to check to see if an email is in a valid format with regular expressions.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION isValidEmailFormat
(
    @Email varchar(100)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Result bit

   SET @Result = (SELECT CASE
                     WHEN @Email LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.)+  (com|org|edu|nz|au])%' 
                       THEN 1
                       ELSE 0
                  END AS Valid)
   RETURN @Result
END
```

Am I doing something wrong with my regular expression? Or do I have to do something more to compare a varchar to a regular expression?

-Edit-

Right now, whatever string I put in returns a 0, even if the email format itself is correct.

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but there's an extra `]` after `au`.

Comment: @acheong87 That wasn't the issue. Thank you, though because that could help me later down the road when I find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that no, it cannot be done. The syntax for [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is not the same as (and way less powerful than) regular expressions. See also [SQL Server Regular expressions in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql)

But you can make the hop to .Net and do the matching there. You can instantiate a `VBScript.RegExp` inside T-SQL using [sp_OACreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189763%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and use that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.isValidEmailFormat
(
    @Email varchar(100)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pattern varchar(4000)
    SET @pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.)+(com|org|edu|nz|au)'
    DECLARE @Result bit

    DECLARE @objRegexExp INT
    EXEC sp_OACreate 'VBScript.RegExp', @objRegexExp OUT

    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'Pattern', @pattern
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'IgnoreCase', 1
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'MultiLine', 0
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'Global', false
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'CultureInvariant', true

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @objRegexExp, 'Test', @Result OUT, @Email

    EXEC sp_OADestroy @objRegexExp

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Do take a peek at [Regex email verification error - using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371542/regex-email-verification-error-using-javascript?rq=1) to see if you want to be a bit less restrictive on what characters are allowed.

Comment: Thank you @flup.  I was trying to avoid writing a program, but I guess I will have to.  I have a program that uses this, I just didn't want to compare customer data in two different places.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd call it a program. You can instantiate the regexp object INSIDE SQL Server and call its methods. I'll add the code to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update! The only error in your code is that you need to SET @pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.)+  (com|org|edu|nz|au])'

Comment: Also, was able to create the function, however, I am still getting a result of 0.  My test was 'ckosmerick@hotmail.com'

Comment: Need to lose a space before the (com

Answer (score 2):

I used @flup 's answer and updated the RegExp pattern as follows:

- dots are allowed in the portion before @, but not as first or last character there
- the expression is anchored to start and end of string with ^ and $
- specific TLDs and country codes were added for the data I was using

The TLDs are whitelisted explicitly to exclude many typos where .com was entered as .co or .cm -- valid country codes for Colombia or Cameroon but not for my data.

The updated line:

```
SET @pattern = '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.)+(com|org|edu|net|ca|au|coop|de|ee|es|fm|fr|gr|ie|in|it|jp|me|nl|nu|ru|uk|us|za)$'
```

I hope this adds value to an already-excellent answer.