# How to query for only email values?

Tags: sql, plsql

Using SQL only, is there a way to query  all values that are emails from a column of misc data?
I tried `like '%@%'`, but there could be texts like this: `Fort Knox @ Room 123`.

Edit: Regex is unavailable.
I've also tried `like '%@%.%'` but did not cover cases with spaces.

Comment: what flavor of sql? what else have you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523789/sql-email-verification-function-using-regex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801166/sql-script-to-find-invalid-email-addresses

Comment: sql database are for structured data. if you're storing "random" text in a field, then don't expect the database help you try to create order out of chaos.

Comment: @MarcB I wish I was the one that designed the database...I'm just a minion for an organization with existing systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/467492/1) for you.

```
 SELECT *
  FROM TABLENAME
  WHERE email LIKE '%@%.%'
    AND email NOT LIKE '% %';
```

Comment: This is also the final conclusion I reached.

Comment: But this is not working if i have email-ids eg. somu_som@gmail.c

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using CLR functions, I'd suggest writing a .NET method which uses a proper regular expression (you can find various ones online) to validate the email address, then calling that function as part of your query.

```
select * from whatever
where dbo.IsThisAnEmailAddress(myColumn) = 1
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will be painfully slow if you have a lot of records in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) in your query to get at the emails. There are tons of links on this site to valid email regexes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others, RegEx is better, however, if not available, try the following

```
WHERE fieldName LIKE '%@%' 
      AND fieldName LIKE '%.%' 
      AND charindex(' ',fieldName)=0
```

It's not great, and slow, but should get you pretty close.   I.E  Contains both an @ and an . and no spaces...

SQLFiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f6d8/1