# Email validation using RegEX (SQL)

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql, data-cleaning, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to validate email in SQL using RegEX to achieve below criteria.

Create a query (use the operator LIKE) that searches for all the Email Addresses that contain:

1. Only one symbol “@”
2. At least one symbol “.”
3. If there is only one “.” symbol it should be after the symbol “@” (and not before it)
4. At least 6 characters
5. The symbols “.” and “@” must not be next to each other
6. The symbol “.” or “@” must not be at the beginning or end of the address
   In addition, the Email Address must not contain the following symbols: “=”, “_”, “-“, “+”, “&”, “<”, “>” or “,”.

I tried writing a query and I have considered all the above point except the **at least 6 character condition**. I am getting the results but all of them is getting displayed as invalid, I am not sure why.

Below is the query that I wrote:

```sql
SELECT EmailAddress 
CASE WHEN EmailAddress Like '%^[A-Za-z0-9._%\-+!#$&/=?^|~]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]+$%' THEN 'Valid'
ELSE 'INVALID' END
AS valid_email
FROM Database
Where EmailAddress is not null
```

Comment: Regexs aren’t good for validating email addresses

Comment: Hey @DanielA.White
Thanks for the comment. Is there any other way to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Email Verification Function using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523789/sql-email-verification-function-using-regex)

Comment: Should `user@host.invalid` be treated as valid? Note that [RFC2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) tells us that nothing with domain ending `.invalid` should ever work. How about: `user@123456789a.com` (could exist but domain is not currently registered)? How about: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@cam.ac.uk` (domain is valid but there is no such local part currently) ?

Comment: At least have the terminology right. SQL Server does not support regex, it supports globbong which have very limited capabilities.

Comment: BTW, if SQL Server would have supported regex, half of the SO SQL questions would become obsolete.

Comment: myname+purpose@gmail.com is a valid email address and much more common to not consider valid. There are many weird possible email addresses though. https://www.netmeister.org/blog/email.html

Answer (score 1):

Standard `LIKE` doesn't handle regex.

I don't recommend using the following code but it satisfies your criteria:

```
SELECT
    EmailAddress,
    CASE
        WHEN (
            ( NOT EmailAddress LIKE '%@%@%' )    -- 1
            AND ( EmailAddress LIKE '%.%' )      -- 2
            AND ( EmailAddress LIKE '%@%.%' )    -- 3
            AND ( EmailAddress LIKE '______%' )  -- 4
            AND ( NOT (                          -- 5
                ( EmailAddress LIKE '%@.%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%.@%' )
            ) )
            AND ( NOT (                          -- 6(a)
                ( EmailAddress LIKE '@%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '.%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%@' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%.' )
            ) )
            AND ( NOT (                          -- 6(b)
                ( EmailAddress LIKE '%=%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%-%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%+%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%&%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%<%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%>%' )
                OR ( EmailAddress LIKE '%,%' )
            ) )
        ) THEN 'Valid'
        ELSE 'INVALID'
    END
    AS valid_email
FROM Database
Where EmailAddress IS NOT NULL
;
```

Notes:

- `=`, `_`,`-`, `+` and `&` are perfectly valid in the local part
- `-` is valid in the domain part
- `<`, `>` and `,` are valid in the local part if properly quoted
- this expression does not correctly classify email addresses in general
- no expression can determine a priori whether or not an address actually exists, even if it is syntactically valid
- I used `Database` because you did, but you probably meant `Database.Table`

Comment: Hi @jhnc,
Unfortunately, I am not able to upvote the answer but thank you so much. It worked!
I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @ShubhamVajpayee you really shouldn't do email validation this way. it excludes many perfectly-valid email addresses

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could tell me the other ways to achieve this as I am not aware of any other ways :(

Comment: @ShubhamVajpayee depends what "achieve this" means. my code does what you requested but does not validate email correctly. The syntax of a valid email address is very complicated. The only reliable way to check validity is to do a call-out (eg. send email to the address requesting confirmation and update your table when you receive the reply - consider e-commerce site registration). Even that is time-limited: addresses that exist when you test can be deleted in future.

Comment: @ShubhamVajpayee [serious](https://mailtrap.io/blog/verify-email-address-without-sending/) [tongue-in-cheek](https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643)